# I'm worried about a mysterious warning message in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an import statement like this:

```dart
// Package imports:
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';  // here
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
```

Here in `import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';`
 `Sort directive sections alphabetically. I get the warning Try sorting the directives.dartdirectives_ordering`.
How can I get rid of this warning?

postscript:
I don't want to use `ignore` to ignore this warning, is it possible to remove the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You can add the following directive to the top of your file:

// ignore_for_file: directives_ordering
This will tell the linter to ignore the warning for this particular file.

Option 2: You can disable the warning globally by adding the following line to your analysis_options.yaml file:

linter:
rules:
directives_ordering: false
This will disable the warning for all files in your project.

Option 3: You can also disable the warning for specific directives by adding the following directive to the line before the directive:

// ignore: directives_ordering
import 'dart:async';